# How can I use values found in sub a in sub b

Tags: excel, vba

The value obtained in the first sub does not carry onto the next, how do I go about doing so?

This is just a small part of the codes, there are many other variables and other user inputs that do not allow me to combine the subs.

```
Private Sub lbEY_AfterUpdate()

Dim sd As Date
Dim ed As Date
Dim fromd As String
Dim tod As String

sm = Month(DateValue("01-" & lbSM & "-1900"))
em = Month(DateValue("01-" & lbEM & "-1900"))

sd = DateSerial(lbSY, sm, 1)
ed = DateSerial(lbEY, em, 1)

    fromd = Format(sd, "mmmm yyyy")
    tod = Format(ed, "mmmm yyyy")

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Range("A1").Value = "For dates " & fromd & " to " & tod & ":"
'This prints out "For dates  to :"

End Sub
```

e.g. fromd is January 2019 and tod is March 2019.
The ideal outcome would be for the value in Range A1 to be" For dates January 2019 to March 2019:"
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is still an error in the code, `& tod ":"` there is `&` missing. Why the output looks like `"For dates  to :"` is because the `Option Explicit` is missing. Without this statement, the `fromd` and `tod` are actually created as local variables of the `Click` procedure. So add `Option Explicit` and then you will get compile error. So then you will need to declare the variable outside of the procedure, at the module level and they will be accessible form all the procedures in that module. [More info](https://wellsr.com/vba/excel/vba-variable-scope/).

Comment: @dee Thank you! How do I go about declaring the variable outside of the procedure? I still don't quite get the details on the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a variable outside of a procedure is quite simple, as you can see in this example:

```
Dim a As Integer

Sub test1()
 a = a + 1
End Sub

Sub test2()
a = a + 1
End Sub

Sub test3()
a = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

I've launched `test3()`, after having put value 4 in cell `A1`, then I've run `test1()` two times and `test2()` one time. Then I put a breakpoint in `test1()`, and in the immediate window, I've entered:

```
? a
```

The response was 7.

Comment: that was all it took! Thank you! I've just added `Dim fromd As String` and `Dim tod As String` all the way up top and it worked!